# When is the center of the quotient equals 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, quotient-set

I want to prove or disprove this statement: If $H = Z(G),$ then $Z(G/H) = 1.$

I have seen an example here [Between the center of a quotient group and the total center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759849/between-the-center-of-a-quotient-group-and-the-total-center) that shows that in some cases that is correct. I want to know if this statement is correct in general or not. and if it is correct how can I prove it?

Could anyone help me with that, please?

Comment: Do you know the quaternion group? There $Q/Z(Q)$ is a Klein $4$-group, hence abelian.

Comment: Would you be able to un-accept my answer? Think it's best if I delete it so people don't go away thinking this is a valid solution, also strictly speaking I don't deserve the rep for the answer either.

Comment: @SeraPhim I did

Comment: Thanks, deleted my answer now.