# If $G$ is finitely generated with $\mathcal{Z}(G)$ finite, $N \triangleleft G$ finite, then $\mathcal{Z}(G/N)$ is finite.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, finitely-generated, quotient-group

I'm looking for a reference in the literature for the fact stated in the title, i.e.

If $G$ is a finitely generated group with $\mathcal{Z}(G)$ finite and $N$ is a finite normal subgroup of $G$, then $\mathcal{Z}(G/N)$ is finite.

Here $\mathcal{Z}(\cdot)$ denotes the center of a group.

I'm sure there must be some textbook on group theory that contains this result. For a proof, check the comment by Derek Holt below.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759849/between-the-center-of-a-quotient-group-and-the-total-center) is a reference about the relationship of $Z(G)$ and $Z(G/N)$ in general.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not provide a reference. I have a proof of this fact, but I would prefer to refer to a book or something.

Comment: And we would prefer (perhaps) to see your nice proof! This would help to see if it is true and to point out the right reference (so far I haven't found it, but i didn't search long). Of course, someone might know this immediately, but for me a proof would be interesting.

Comment: I think it can be proves as follows. Let $Y$ be the inverse image of $Z(G/N)$ in $G$. Then $[Y,G] \le N$ is finite, so the orbits of the conjugation action of $Y$ on $G$ are finite, and hence the index $|Y:C_Y(g)|$ is finite for all $g \in G$. Apply this to the elements $g$ in a finite generating set of $G$, and we get $|Y:C_Y(G)|$ is finite, but $C_Y(G) = Y \cap Z(G)$, which is finite, so $Y$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks Derek, this is basically the proof I had, but written down much more elegantly!